# How to propagate a parameter for joins in a ORM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

This is a [sequel of a question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758864/schema-evolution-strategies-preferably-for-net). So far the strategy for Schema Evolution problem I'm trying to implement is Slowly changing dimension. The problem that I have now looks as following. Consider the following data model:

```
class Bar
{
    int id;
    int param;

    double x;
    double y;
}

class Foo
{
    int id;
    int param;

    string name;
    string description;

    collection<Bar> bars;
}

class Delta
{
    int id;
    int param;

    double rating;
}

class RootEntity
{
    int id;
    int param;

    collection<Foo> foos;
    collection<Delta> deltas;
}
```

Note, that all entities have `int param` attribute. It has the same name but it is not foreign key.
This is quite simplified model, just as an example. Consider that collections are **huge** and object tree is way more sophisticated. In EntityFramework technology 
I can do something like:

```
  class MyDbContext : DbContext
  {
        public DbSet<RootEntity> rootEntities { get; set; }
  }
```

What I want to do is limit the selection by `param`. That can be as following

```
dbContext.rootEntities.Where(e => e.param == some_value);
```

The problem is that only dbContext.rootEntities will be filtered in generated SQL code. The rest (joins with Foo, Bar and Delta) will not be filtered.
Hence is the question: how to propagate `.Where(e => e.param == some_value)` to all joins for underlying objects selection?

I'm looking at solutions for EntityFramework or NHibernate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With NHibernate you can use `Filter` per table like this:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    ApplyFilter("Param", "param = :paramValue");
}

public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    ApplyFilter("Param", "param = :paramValue");
}

public class XyzMap : ClassMap<Xyz>
{
    // This can be the (abstract?) base class map
    ApplyFilter("Param", "param = :paramValue");
}
```

Before you call any entity by the session enable the filter:

```
Session.EnableFilter("Param").SetParameter("paramValue", objValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, we'll give it a try.