# Cannot get NHibernate filter to filter entities -- am I missing concept?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

A week ago I asked on [how to propagate a parameter for joins in a ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827934/how-to-propagate-a-parameter-for-joins-in-a-orm). The suggested solution looks as promising -- using NHibernate filters. Here is what I'm doing:

Filter class:

```
public class VersionFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public static readonly string Name = typeof(VersionFilter).AssemblyQualifiedName;

    public static readonly string Parameter = "AsOf";

    private static readonly string SqlParameter = ":" + Parameter;
    private static readonly string Condition
        = " ISNULL(" + SqlParameter + ") AND ( ISNULL(ValidTo) )" +
          " OR ( ValidFrom < " + SqlParameter + " AND " + SqlParameter + "  <= ValidTo )"
    ;
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, IType> ParameterTypes = 
        new Dictionary<string, IType>
        {
            {Parameter, NHibernateUtil.Int64}
        }
    ;

    public VersionFilter(): base(Name, Condition, ParameterTypes, true)
    {
    }
}
```

In Main:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log.Info("VersionedDataModel1.Program::start");
        try
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddFilterDefinition(new VersionFilter());

            var types = DomainClasses(typeof(Program).Assembly, "VersionedDataModel1.Domain");

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                cfg.AddInputStream(HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(type));
            }
            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            {
                var schema = new SchemaExport(cfg);
                schema.Drop(false, true);
                schema.Execute(false, true, false);
                //new SchemaExport(cfg).Drop(false, true);
                //new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
                //new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One of Entity classes:

```
[Class]
public class Store : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<Product> _products = new List<Product>();
    private ICollection<Employee> _staff = new List<Employee>();

    [Property(NotNull = true)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Set(0, Table = "ProductsInStore", Lazy = CollectionLazy.False, Cascade = "none")]
    [Key(1, Column = "StoreId")]
    [ManyToMany(2, Column = "ProductId", ClassType = typeof(Product))]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get { return _products; } set { _products = value; } }

    [Key(1, Column = "StoreId")]
    [OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(Employee))]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Staff { get { return _staff; } set { _staff = value; } }

    public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
        Products.Add(product);
    }

    public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        employee.Store = this;
        Staff.Add(employee);
    }
}
```

To query data I do the following:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> QueryAllProducts(long? asOf)
    {
        using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            session.EnableFilter(VersionFilter.Name).SetParameter(VersionFilter.Parameter, asOf);
            return session.QueryOver<Product>().List<Product>();
        }
    }
```

In NHibernate debug log I see the following. When I construct SessionFactory. I see the following error, that I'm not sure how to interpret:

`2015-04-30 13:53:32,398 [1] ERROR NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - filter-def for filter named 'VersionedDataModel1.VersionFilter, VersionedDataModel1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was never used to filter classes nor collections.
This may result in unexpected behavior during queries`

Further on in log I see no reference to the filter and neither my Product collection is filtered. May be I'm missing the concept.

My idea is to apply this filter (VersionFilter) for the whole session so that all entities that are queried will have this addidional `WHERE ...`  condition to be used.

Hence is the question -- what am I missing with Filter/FilterDefinition ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You already registered the filter to nhibernate, now you have to call a reference in your mapping class or collections.

I have never used mapping by attributes but i asume you need to use  `NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Filter` to relate the filter with the entity (class level)

Or dynamic like this:

```
var filterParametersType = new Dictionary<string, Itype>(1);
filterParametersType.Add("current", NhibernateUtil.Enum(typeof(ContextType)));
cfg.AddFilterDefinition(new FilterDefinition("contextFilter", ":current = Context", filterParametersType));

foreach (var mapping in cfg.ClassMappings)
{
    if (typeof(IContextAware).IsAssignableFrom(mapping.MappedClass))
    {
        mapping.AddFilter("contextFilter", ":current = Context");
    }
}
```

You can read more [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/contextual-data-using-nhibernate-filters.html) in nhibernate documentation.